# Определение наличия в HashSet возможного значения

Tags: java

Функции на вход подается класс, у которого 3 поля - HashMap и 3 возможных значения этих полей (3 возможных кдюча). Дальше мне нужно определить, лежит ли в каждом мэпе одно из тех 3-х значений.
И если в каком-то мэпе встречается, то увеличиваю внутренний счетчик. Пробегаюсь я так: прохожу мэп итератором и, если есть совпадение iterator.next() с возможным значением поля, то увеличиваю счетчик.

В процессе возникла вот такая ошибка:

```
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
```

Что это значит?

```
Iterator<Segment.Age> ageIterator = campaign.getTarget().getAge().iterator();
while ( ageIterator.hasNext() ){
    if ( mapFromAgeToAgeDistribution.containsKey(ageIterator.next()) ){
    ageFitness += mapFromAgeToAgeDistribution.get(ageIterator.next()); // рагается на эту строчку
    }
}
```

Comment: Проще надо делать: пробовать добавить в каждый сет это значение, в какой не добавится - увеличить счетчик или контейнером проверить.

Comment: а как определить добавилось или нет?

Comment: метод add - вернет false

Comment: ой, виноват, тупанул...
а что делать, если возможные значения лежат в HashSet?
т.е. мне нужно проверить лежат ли все элементы сета среди элементов данного HashSet. И если какие-то лежат, то нужно достать значения совпавших ключей.

Answer (score 1):

Ругается, потому что ты два раза в одном проходе цикла выполняешь ageIterator.next(). Соответственно в условии if'а у тебя проверяется одно значение, а в теле if'а - используется другое. Сделай так:

```
Iterator<Segment.Age> ageIterator = campaign.getTarget().getAge().iterator();
while ( ageIterator.hasNext() ){
    Segment.Age ageItem = ageIterator.next();
    if ( mapFromAgeToAgeDistribution.containsKey(ageItem) ){
        ageFitness += mapFromAgeToAgeDistribution.get(ageItem);
    }
}
```

И будет счастье.